# Is there a simple way to initialise a dict with NoneType as a key?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, nonetype

for formating reasons, I wanted to make a dict with datatypes as keys.

```
formats={int:"{:^}", float:"{:^.4f}", str:"{:^}"}
print(formats[type(var)].format(var))
```

However if there is a chance that var may contain the `None` value, I'm forced to write something like:

```
formats={int:"{:^}", float:"{:^.4f}", str:"{:^}", type(None):"{:}"}
```

Because NoneType is not recognized as a valid type. Is there another (more pythonic) way to specify this ?

Comment: using type(None) is simpler because I only need to use it at initialization. It's just that it makes me call the function type when I could have a type name as for other types

Comment: I see. That seems like a non-issue to me, but I'd be curious to hear the answer anyway.

Comment: Well, I was adding the value for `formats[type(none)] = "{}"` after the initial declaration, until I realized there was no reason I couldn't put it directly inside this initial declaration. But I must admit having to use `type(None)` instead of `NoneType` doesn't feel very pythonic.